# What does declaring function at the start of a line do?

Tags: r, arrays, string, syntax

I encountered this code:

```
    res <- lapply(strsplit(s, "\n")[[1]],
    (function (str) paste(rev(strsplit(str, "")[[1]]), collapse = "")))
```

The secodnd line reverses each of the splitted strings at the first line.
How does it do that? Namely, what does calling 'function' at the start do?

Comment: Please create a reproducible example, using an existing or toy dataset

Comment: You use this piece of code with a string of multiple lines. It essentially breaks them down and reverses each line. You could do s <- "abc\ndef", at the start, to get the feeling .

Answer (score 2):

Calling `lapply` takes and performs some function on each list element. It takes the form `lapply(list_data, some_function)`. So, for instance, if I have a list of integers and want to find out how many integers are in each list element, I would run:

```
list_data <- list(list1 = 1:5,
                  list2 = 6:10,
                  list3 = 11:30)
lapply(list_data, length)
```

The function here is `length`, which is a function that is inherent in R. Some functions aren't defined in R, say if I want define my own formula for each value in the list, I could define my own function. Calling a `function` allows users to define a function that is not already in R or an R library. Like so:

```
lapply(list_data, function(x) x^2+4-x^3)
```

The function here is `x^2+4-x^3`, which is not defined in R programming itself.

So in your example, your data is `strsplit(s, "\n")[[1]]` and it is taking that data and applying the function `paste(rev(strsplit(str, "")[[1]]), collapse = ""))` to each element in the data.

Note that in my example, I put `function(x)` - your example puts `function(str)` - what's in the parentheses doesn't matter and is user defined. For example `lapply(list_data, function(str) str^2+4-str^3)` will return the same thing as `lapply(list_data, function(x) x^2+4-x^3)`

**Please note that broad "learning" style questions like this are not exactly what this site is for, and this question will likely get removed and/or receive some negative feedback.** Since you are new to this site and to R, I'm providing this answer but I would not be surprised if the question is removed. Just trying to help both you and the SO community!